# How to create React Native npm package that requires iOS cocoapod dependency

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, npm, cocoapods

I am trying to create a react native npm native module using https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module. The module requires a third party pod as a dependency. I have included the reference to the pod dependency in the modules podspec as a s.dependency. When installing the npm package module into my host app, it will not install it unless the pod dependency is installed in the host app as expected. However when I try to build the App I receive this error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). Is this the correct way to reference a third party pod in my npm native module? Currently using xcode15, RN 72.8.

Thank you

I expect the app to build successfully using the referenced and installed pod present already in the app.

Answer (score 0):

- The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that when you install your npm package module, it doesn't automatically link the pod dependency to your host app. This is why you're getting the linker command failed error.
- You need to manually link the pod dependency to your host app.

  ```
  install pod install
  ```
- Open your module's package.json file & Add a "postinstall" script to the "scripts" section & save it.

  ```
  "scripts": {
   "postinstall": "cd ../../ios && pod install && cd ../../"
  }
  ```
- Please note that this solution assumes that the host app is using CocoaPods for dependency management. If the host app is using a different method for managing dependencies, you may need to adjust the postinstall script accordingly.